# Does a conversion take place when uploading a texture of GL_ALPHA format (glTexImage2D)?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

The documentation for glTexImage2D says

GL_RED (for GL) / GL_ALPHA (for GL ES). "The GL converts it to floating point and assembles it into an RGBA element by attaching 0 for green and blue, and 1 for alpha. Each component is clamped to the range [0,1]."

I've read through the GL ES specs to see if it specifies whether the GPU memory is actually 32bit vs 8bit, but it seems rather vague. Can anyone confirm whether uploading a texture as GL_RED / GL_ALPHA gets converted from 8bit to 32bit on the GPU?

I'm interested in answers for GL and GL ES.

Comment: AFAIK conversions are not available on most mobile devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've read through the GL ES specs to see if it specifies whether the GPU memory is actually 32bit vs 8bit, but it seems rather vague.

Well, that's what it is. The actual details are left for the actual implementation to decide. Giving such liberties in the specification allows actual implementations to contain optimizations tightly tailored to the target system. For example a certain GPU may cope better with a 10 bits per channel format, so it's then at liberty to convert to such a format.

So it's impossible to say in general, but for a specific implementation (i.e. GPU + driver) a certain format will be likely choosen. Which one depends on GPU and driver.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from what datenwolf has said, I found the following in the "POWERVR SGX 
OpenGL ES 2.0 Application Development Recommendations" document:

> **6.3. Texture Upload**
>   When you upload textures to the OpenGL ES driver via glTexImage2D, the input data is usually in  linear scanline
>   format. Internally, though, POWERVR SGX uses a twiddled layout (i.e.
>   following a  plane-filling curve) to greatly improve memory access
>   locality when texturing. Because of this different  layout uploading
>   textures will always require a somewhat expensive reformatting
>   operation,  regardless of whether the input pixel format exactly
>   matches the internal pixel format or not.
>
> For this reason we
>   recommend that you upload all required textures at application or
>   level start-up  time in order to not cause any framerate dips when
>   additional textures are uploaded later on.
>
> You should especially
>   avoid uploading texture data mid-frame to a texture object that has
>   already  been used in the frame.